# How to get selected row data and update in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm trying to change only 1 column and row upon the click of a button and also update mySQL according to the String. I managed to write a code but its changing the whole column into the String instead of the selected row. I'm trying to change only the value of the selected row. How can i do that?

```
private void jButtonBorrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableBooks1.getModel();
    int row = jTableBooks1.getSelectedRow();

    String notavail = model.getValueAt(row, 2).toString();
    notavail = "Not Available";

    PreparedStatement ps;  
    String query = "UPDATE `Books` SET `Availability`=?";      

    try {
        ps = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);            
        ps.setString(1, notavail);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book Borrowed Successfully!");
        BookMenu bm = new BookMenu();
        bm.setVisible(true);
        bm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.dispose();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}       

public ArrayList<Books> booksList(){
    ArrayList<Books> booksList = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM `Books`";
    try {
        ps = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Books book;

        while (rs.next()){
            book = new Books(rs.getString("author"),rs.getString("bookname"),rs.getString("ISBN"), rs.getString("Course"),rs.getString("Year"),rs.getString("Availability"));
            booksList.add(book);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Register.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return booksList; 
}

public void showBooks(){
    ArrayList<Books>list = booksList();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTableBooks1.getModel();
    Object[] row = new Object[6];

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        row[0] =list.get(i).getAuthor();
        row[1] =list.get(i).getBookname(); 
        row[2] = list.get(i).getAvailability();
        model.addRow(row);
    }
```

As mentioned above i would like to change only the data in the selected row. Attached is a picture of how it is and how i want it to be.

[image: How it is]

[image: How i want it to be upon click]

Comment: `where` clause in your sql?

Comment: How can i add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `String query = "UPDATE Books SET Availability = ?";`

You need a `WHERE` clause in your update query, else all rows get updated.

Assuming that the book name and author can be used as a primary key, this might do the job :

```
String author = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
String bookname = model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
String query = 
    "UPDATE Books SET availability = ? WHERE author = ? AND bookname = ?";
try {
    ps = dbConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, notavail);
    ps.setString(2, author);
    ps.setString(3, bookname);
    ...
```

Comment: So i added this: 

`String query = "UPDATE `Books` SET `Availability`=? WHERE `author`=" + model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();`


but get this error: 

    Jan 17, 2019 5:03:15 AM libraryinformationsystem.BorrowBook jButtonBorrowActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Takada' in 'where clause'

Comment: @Javay14 : do you have a field in `Books` that can be used to uniquely identify a record ?

Comment: apart from the author name no. Bookname and author are unique for the time being

Comment: OK let's assume that author name and book name combined can be considered as a primary key ?

Comment: Yes i guess. Keep getting this error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Takada' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you will need to add `WHERE` clause. However, you will also need to add two conditions since I beleive an auther can have multiple books. 
So it should look like:

```
String query = "UPDATE `Books` SET `Availability`=? WHERE auther =? and book_name=?"
```

Comment: For testing purposes the author will only have 1 book. But if i put a question mark after "WHERE author =?", What parameters will i put?

Comment: You will pass it the the Author name from the table. You need to get them from the model and then add them to query like 

ps.setString(1, notavail);
    ps.setString(2, author);
    ps.setString(3, bookname);
you can hardcode them for testing and then pass them from the table.